# Global variable in JSP

Tags: jsp

i what to create the common file which contions  common import  and data base connection in common jsp file and then i will include that file and use the variable and connection which i cretaed in common.
Simply, how do I create a global variable in JSP, such that I can access it across other JSP pages and/or inside frames/iframes? I tried <%!..%> but I got an error that the variable could not be resolved in a separate jsp page. Is it even possible to access JSP variables in more than one page without resorting to query strings, session variables, ?
i do not what use servlets.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question, but if you want to connect to a DB, you should create a java class (not a JSP) that handles DB Connections, and then you simply import that java class on every JSP that needs access to the DB, or even better, you should have java classes and run your DB queries there instead of doing it from your JSP's, then you can import the class you need and retrieve whatever info the java class is getting.

There are no global variables across JSP's, you can only send parameters between them, but in this case, you don't need that. Also, there's many Connection Pool libraries that can do all the hard work for you, so you only have to configure it according your needs.